# Do not pass when signals flashing. Grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality

https://www.flickr.com/photos/islandyorkie/14757675659/

This warning, or similar, is on most every school bus I've seen.

It bothers me because I can't find the verb in the *when* phrase.  I assume "flashing" is a gerund form, and the sentence is missing the verb *are*.

Have I misinterpreted this?  Is this construction used in other situations?

Comment: OK, so maybe they should have talked to an English teacher at a school on the route.  But these kinds of constructions are common in signage, headlines, and other places where space is at a premium.  I prefer "Do not pass when signals flash."  I think it's kinda catchy.

Comment: It is *telegram text* where you economise on words (People probably don't remember telegrams, when you paid by the word). But clearly it is saying *Do not pass when signals (ARE) flashing*.

Comment: "Do not pass when signals flash" is not only shorter but makes perfect sense.  I wonder why "flashing" was opted for.

Comment: Road signs are rarely grammatical, or even unambiguous.  They fall into the same category as advertising slogans - catch the eye quickly.

Comment: Call me old-fashioned, but I still hold schools to a higher standard than marketing wonks. No, I take that back—I'm just as perturbed by billboards as by buses.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock what a satisfying expression is 'marketing wonks'!Thank you, I will be using that.

Comment: It's "sign language".  It need not make perfect grammatical sense.

Comment: I reverted the question because the edits changed the nature of the question, e.g by changing the OP's  'gerund' to 'present participle'.  An error of fact (rather than, e.g. spelling or punctuation) in a question is useful context that allows us to answer better.

Comment: Apologies for gerund rather than present participle - I learnt to speak English by talking and it wasn't until I learnt other languages that I encountered "gerunds".  Anyway - "word ending in -ing", in case you weren't sure what I was talking about.

Answer (score 1):

> Do not pass when signals flashing.
>
> I can't find the verb in the when phrase. I assume "flashing" is a
>   gerund form, and the sentence is missing the verb are.

***Update***: 17 Sep 2015 - The question was edited after I cut and paste the above from it.

You are right about the missing verb. The full sentence would be:

*Do not pass when the signals are flashing.*

However in that case 'flashing' is not a gerund, it is a present participle.

There is a useful discussion on the difference here. [THE -ING FORMS  edufind.com](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/ing-forms/)

Comment: As for gerunds versus participles, this is a silly mocking of Latin into English, and [many modern grammarians have de-emphasized the distinction and some have dispensed with the distinction altogether.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_gerund-participles)